# Change the foreground color of statusbars in irssi?

Tags: linux, colors, irssi

I've changed the terminal colors and now irssi statusbars have white text on light blue background. I would like to change the foreground color of the irssi statusbars to black but can't figure out how to do it. I don't want to download a whole theme, I only want to change this one color.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

-Martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colors of statusbars items in irssi are defined in default.theme file in irssi configuration directory. It is a plain text file and you can edit it. You can also create your own theme file.

In particular, to change foreground color for statusbar from white to black, find this line:

```
sb_background = "%4%w";
```

and replace it with:

```
sb_background = "%4%k";
```

The full list of color codes is available here: https://github.com/irssi/irssi/blob/master/docs/formats.txt

Answer (score -2):

If you are using gnome-terminal right click, profile, profile preferences, colors, palette, then pallete entry 5 is the background and entry 8 is the foreground.

Comment: Great, unfortunately I'm using OSX Terminal. It also sound like such a change would affect other things then the statusbar which uses the same color?

Comment: @Marlun you are runnin' linux or osx? ...

Comment: I was on OS X but have moved on to running weechat instead of irssi on a VPS with Debian Linux.